# Pass variable as an input argument to a function inside another function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, functions, parameter

I am new to PostgresQL and having some trouble in feeding a function with a variable from an outer function. (maybe it is not possible...)

Inside a function I am trying to assign a value from calling another function like this:
left_bipolar_n:=public.convert_to_decimal(left_bipolar);

When I call the function, If I use something like '122' as an argument instead of "left_bipolar" it works just fine but just as it is I get:
Error: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "  "

I should say that Function convert_to_decimal expects text

Complete code:

```
-- FUNCTION: public.AmateurExercise(numeric)
--drop FUNCTION public."AmateurExercise"(numeric);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."AmateurExercise"(
    n numeric)
    RETURNS numeric
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
declare 
bipolar text;
tamanho integer;
left_bipolar text;
right_bipolar text;
left_bipolar_n numeric;
right_bipolar_n numeric;

begin
bipolar:=public.convert_to_bipolar8(n);
tamanho=length(bipolar);
if tamanho/2 =floor (tamanho/2) then 
begin
left_bipolar=left(bipolar,tamanho/2);
right_bipolar=right(bipolar, tamanho/2);
end;
else
left_bipolar=left(bipolar,(tamanho-1)/2);
right_bipolar=right(bipolar, ((tamanho-1)/2)+1);
end if;

left_bipolar_n:=public.convert_to_decimal(left_bipolar);
return left_bipolar_n;

end;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION public."AmateurExercise"(numeric)
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: The error indicates that for some reason left_bipolar contains a space just before the call.  I guess convert_to_bipolar8 must put the space there.  But we can't see the code for it, not what input you called the outer function with.

Comment: @jjanes: right on target. Once I remove the space it works just fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please put this in as an answer and mark it as correct!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answer from a jjanes comment:

"The error indicates that for some reason left_bipolar contains a space just before the call. I guess convert_to_bipolar8 must put the space there. But we can't see the code for it, not what input you called the outer function with"